# C++ template variable and parameter pack expansion

Tags: c++, c++17

In libstdc++ variant source, it defines the following template variable (taken out from the struct _Traits),

```cpp
template<typename... _Types>
  static constexpr bool _S_copy_ctor = 
    (is_copy_constructible_v<_Types> && ...);
```

What does the '&&' do here?

I tried to take out the '&&' it failed to compile, so, what's difference of the two?

```cpp
  static constexpr bool _S_copy_ctor = (is_copy_constructible_v<_Types> && ...);
  static constexpr bool _S_copy_ctor = (is_copy_constructible_v<_Types>    ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this very context, the `&&` is a simple *logical AND* operator called [*fold operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold#Explanation).

It's used to unfold an expression based on `typename... _Types`. Example:

let `_Types` be deduced to `int, double, float`, then the expression:

```
(is_copy_constructible_v<_Types> && ...)
```

will be expanded (*unfolded*) to:

```
(is_copy_constructible_v<int> &&
 is_copy_constructible_v<double> && 
 is_copy_constructible_v<float>)
```

You cannot simply erase the `&&`. It has it's use case.

Comment: Thanks much, Fureeish & Barry! It makes sense now. From this link, https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features#folding-expressions, the fold expressions have the three forms: (... op e) or (e op ...) and (e1 op ... op e2). So, here is the 2nd form being used.

Comment: @Bill, No problem. If this answer answered your question, consider accepting it by clicking the green tick just below its score so future visitors will know that this answer indeed solved the issue.